# How to prevent cells to re-arrange when one cell is moved in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView in which I have 9 cells. 8 cells has images and remaining 1 cell is empty. Now the desired behaviour is that when I click a cell and if the empty cell is around it wether on its left, right, top or bottom, it will move to that empty cell position, and moving's cell position will be empty, and all the other cells will be on their position. But in my case, other cells are also re-arranging to fill the empty cell. How can I prevent that behaviour?